# Converting from Python to C List functions

Tags: python, c, list, function

```
L = [[" " for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]

for i in range (10):
    L[9][i]="*"
for i in range (10):
        L[8][i]="1"
for i in range (10):
        L[7][i]="*"
for i in range (10):
        L[6][i]="3"
for i in range (10):
        L[5][i]="*"

print(L)
print()

def Check_Lines(l):
    for i in range (10):
        x=l[i].count("*")
        if x == 10:
            print ("LINE IS FULL")
            del l[i]
            l.reverse()
            l.append([" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "])
            l.reverse()


Check_Lines(L)
print (L)
```

I wrote the above function in Python as I am more familiar with the python language. What it does is searches a 10 by 10 list and if a single row is filled with * then it would delete it and put a new empty row at the top.

I know c does not have the list functions I used. Is there any easy way of going about what I am doing?

Comment: What have you tried? C language surely doesn't have a native way to manage dynamic lists, what you have are arrays but to use them in a dynamic way you need to work with pointers.

Comment: I didn't know where to begin to rewrite the built in functions with c. I was more of trying to get someone to respond with what you said "Pointers" so I can look it up and understand what I need to do. I don't know the C language at all and I am trying to learn.

Comment: Do some research on linked lists. You'll have to implement the list itself, but it'll be an educational experience. :)

Answer (score 1):

In C unfortunately that problem would be pretty difficult.  Would require you to allocate a memory block for your matrix.  And when you wanted to "remove" a row you'd have to move everything up and free the extra memory at the bottom of the matrix.

If you can use C++ this is much more easily done with STL containers.  You could have a vector of vectors.  Removing a row would be a call to erase:

```
l.erase(pos)  // pos is an iterator at the row you'd like to remove
```